# Show a div in a specific country using geoIP

Tags: php, geoip

Is there any way to display a div (or other element) in only a certain country by using geoIP, using the country codes at https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php

The flow would be something like:

```
<?php
if ($country = CA) {
echo '<div class="1">';
} else {
echo '<div class="2">';
}
?>
```

Can this be done? Can you write it out?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in 2 steps:

1. get IP address of a user
2. get country name based on user IP (via GeoIP extension)

Sample code:

```
<?php
// client IP
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// two letter country code
$country = geoip_country_code_by_name($ip);

if ($country == 'CA') {
    echo '<div class="1">'; // will be displayed only in Canada
} else {
    echo '<div class="2">';
}
```